# stacked barplot converting a variable into a presence absence based percentage for unrelated variables in ggplot2 R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

Following is a sample data frame

```
df <- data.frame(SampleID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
                 Var1 = c(0.1 , 0.5,    0.7,    0,  0,  0,  0.5,    0.2), 
                 Var1PA = c("Present", "Present", "Present", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent",  "Present", "Present"), 
                 Var2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.2), 
                 Var2PA = c("Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Present", "Present", "Present", "Present"))
```

My question started off as seemingly simple, but I could not find a way to edit the dataframe suitably to plot a barplot.

**For Var1, I want to plot a stacked barplot of the percent of times var1 was present in the sample (i.e var1 value > 0) or absent (Similarly for var2 and so on).**

I could determine this percentage by:

```
(1 - sum(df$Var1 == 0) / length(df$Var1)) * 100
```

But how do I convert this into a percentage while plotting?
I looked at many melt options, but there is no unifying criteria for these variables that would make a common X axis

Finally, how does one answer the question above if I want to plot 5 variables from a dataframe of 1000 such column variables?

Edit: Thanks for the answers so far! I have a slight edit to the question
I just added one more variable to my data frame

```
df <- data.frame(SampleID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
             Var1 = c(0.1 , 0.5,    0.7,    0,  0,  0,  0.5,    0.2), 
             Var1PA = c("Present", "Present", "Present", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent",  "Present", "Present"), 
             Var2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.2), 
             Var2PA = c("Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Present", "Present", "Present", "Present"),
             Disease = c("Case", "Control", "Case", "Control", "Case", "Control", "Case", "Control"))
```

I am trying to figure out how to plot the barplot for cases and controls with presence absence stacked within them for Var1PA, Var2PA and so on. If I have the right data frame input, the ggplot2 code would be :
    vars <- c('Var1PA', 'Var2PA', 'Var2PA')
    ##based on the first comment by @rawr
    tt <- data.frame(prop.table(as.table(sapply(df[, vars], table)), 2) * 100)
    ggplot(tt, aes(Disease, Freq)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = Var1), position = "stack", stat="identity") +     facet_grid(~vars)

How do I get percentages for cases (present and absent) and controls (present and absent) for each of the vars? Thanks!

Comment: what should be stacked

Comment: Presence/absence as a percentage, Thanks!

Comment: sorry cant test `vars <- c('Var1PA', 'Var2PA', 'Var2PA'); tt <- data.frame(prop.table(as.table(sapply(df[, vars], table)), 2) * 100); ggplot(tt, aes(Var2, Freq, fill = Var1)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

Comment: A mildly hacky way: `library(tidyverse) ; df %>% gather(var, pa, ends_with('PA')) %>% group_by(var) %>% do(pa = names(table(.$pa)), pct = prop.table(table(.$pa)) * 100) %>% unnest() %>% ggplot(aes(var, pct, fill = pa)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

Comment: @rawr sorry for the late reply thanks for your answer it helped me a lot! If I add another variable Disease to my df, would it be easy with prop.table to get percentages separately for cases (present and absent) and controls (present and absent) within each var?

Comment: If the question you originally asked didn't cover the full complexity you needed, rather than editing the question after it has been answered ("moving the goalposts"), I would recommend you accept the answer and ask a new question referencing this one.

Comment: Ok, I can surely do that, just wanted to avoid redundancy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should generalize nicely. You can, of course, be more selective about the variables you pick.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mdf = df %>% select(SampleID, ends_with("PA")) %>%
    gather(key = Var, value = PA, -SampleID) %>%
    mutate(PA = factor(PA, levels = c("Present", "Absent")))

ggplot(mdf, aes(x = Var, fill = PA)) +
    geom_bar(position = "fill") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

You can add the percentage columns to the long data frame:

```
mdf %>% group_by(Var) %>%
    mutate(p_present = mean(PA == "Present"),
           p_absent = mean(PA == "Absent"))
# Source: local data frame [16 x 5]
# Groups: Var [2]
# 
#    SampleID    Var      PA p_present p_absent
#       <dbl>  <chr>  <fctr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1         1 Var1PA Present     0.625    0.375
# 2         2 Var1PA Present     0.625    0.375
# 3         3 Var1PA Present     0.625    0.375
# 4         4 Var1PA  Absent     0.625    0.375
# 5         5 Var1PA  Absent     0.625    0.375
# 6         6 Var1PA  Absent     0.625    0.375
# 7         7 Var1PA Present     0.625    0.375
# 8         8 Var1PA Present     0.625    0.375
# 9         1 Var2PA  Absent     0.500    0.500
# 10        2 Var2PA  Absent     0.500    0.500
```

Or if you'd rather see a 1-line-per-group summary, replace `mutate` with `summarize`:

```
mdf %>% group_by(Var) %>%
    summarize(p_present = mean(PA == "Present"),
           p_absent = mean(PA == "Absent"))
# # A tibble: 2 × 3
#      Var p_present p_absent
#    <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 Var1PA     0.625    0.375
# 2 Var2PA     0.500    0.500
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer and extremely sorry for the late reply. Life took over..I tried your solution, however its a little hard for me to follow because both gather and mutate are new functions I have not used before. Also I would like to actually see the frequency counts in the final table I am plotting (mdf) in the case of your answer. I have edited the question a little, please let me know if you had any suggestions for the same. I have upvoted your answer..thanks!

Comment: All `mutate` does is create new columns, and `gather` is more or less equivalent to `melt`. (`gather` has a slightly fewer features but simpler syntax.) I'll add a couple lines to put the percentages in the data.

Comment: I have posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859308/calculate-within-variable-percentage-for-stacked-grouped-barplot. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  SampleID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
  Var1 = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.2),
  Var1PA = c("Present", "Present", "Present", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Present", "Present"),
  Var2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.2),
  Var2PA = c("Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Present", "Present", "Present", "Present")
)

reshape::melt(df, c('SampleID')) |> 
  filter(variable == 'Var1' | variable == 'Var2') |> 
  mutate(value1 = ifelse(value == 0, 'Absent', 'Present')) |> 
  group_by(variable) |> count(variable, value1) |> 
  mutate(
    prc = n/sum(n)
  ) |>  as.data.frame() |> 
  ggplot( aes(x = variable, y = prc, fill = value1)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'fill', width = 0.7) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    labs(fill = 'Presence status') +
    geom_text(aes(x = variable, y = prc, label = stat(y)),
              position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: I hadn't caught up with the |> pipe. But there is a nice blog post on it here https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/the-new-r-pipe/. My favorite quote: "For those who use dplyr (or those maniacs that start their scripts with library(tidyverse)..."  :-D