# Calculate within variable percentage for stacked grouped barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a grouped stacked barplot for several different variables, var1PA, var2PA by calculating how many times each var was present or absent within a case and a control.

```
 df <- data.frame(SampleID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
         Var1 = c(0.1 , 0.5,    0.7,    0,  0,  0,  0.5,    0.2), 
         Var1PA = c("Present", "Present", "Present", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent",  "Present", "Present"), 
         Var2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.2), 
         Var2PA = c("Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Present", "Present", "Present", "Present"),
         Disease = c("Case", "Control", "Case", "Control", "Case", "Control", "Case", "Control"))
```

I want to calculate percentage of present and absent for each case and each control within each var and am unable to do it with prop table,

```
vars <- c('Var1PA', 'Var2PA')
   tt <- data.frame(prop.table(as.table(sapply(df[, vars], table)), 2) * 100)
##above line does not calculate the percentage of present absent individually for cases 
##and controls within each var
```

if I am able to do it then I can use ggplot2 to plot:

```
ggplot(tt, aes(Disease, Freq)) +
geom_bar(aes(fill = Var1), position = "stack", stat="identity") + facet_grid(~vars)
```

How do I get percentages for cases (present and absent) and controls (present and absent) for each of the vars? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly simple extension of the last question. In getting the data to long format, we treat `Disease` just like `SampleID`, otherwise the code is identical:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
mdf = df %>% select(SampleID, Disease, ends_with("PA")) %>%
    gather(key = Var, value = PA, -SampleID, -Disease) %>%
    mutate(PA = factor(PA, levels = c("Present", "Absent")))
```

We can then go directly to a plot relying on `ggplot` to compute the percentages. This is identical the plot in the previous question, but with `Disease` on the x-axis and the faceting added.

```
ggplot(mdf, aes(Disease)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = PA), position = "fill") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    facet_grid(~Var)
```

If you want the percentages in the data frame, we can do that with a little more manipulation:

```
df_summ = mdf %>% group_by(Disease, Var) %>%
    mutate(n = n()) %>%  ## calculate n for Disease and Var groups
    group_by(Disease, Var, PA) %>%
    summarize(Percent = n() / first(n))  ## calculate the fraction P/A in each group
```

With that summarized data frame, we can create the same plot as above more explicitly:

```
ggplot(df_summ, aes(Disease, Percent)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = PA), position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    facet_grid(~Var)
```

Comment: Hi Gregor, thanks for the solutions! Very cool use of dplyr and tidyr functions. A quick question, what do the negative signs `-SampleID -Disease` indicate? Also I had not previously seen an extensive use of  `%>%`. Is that to avoid naming multiple new intermediate dfs?

Comment: Hi Gregor, quick question, in your code above can `ends_with("PA")` be replaced with more generic like a vector of strings. Suppose i provide
`vars = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3")`, can `select` use this vector instead? I have multiple variables that end with PA and I want to selectively plot only a few of them. Thanks!, Manasi

Comment: I found a solution in the documentation using `one_of(vars)` In case anyone ever reads this chain!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ggplot(tt, aes(Var2, Freq, fill=Var1)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  xlab('Variable') + guides(fill=guide_legend("Variable"))
```

[image]